# Window 7: Windows Installer always Crashes

Tags: windows-7, crash, windows-installer

Recently everytime i wanted to install a program that uses Windows default installer, the installation process will just crash.

Here is a log of it:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B94u0_R6vixWbmxDNHQxM1RhMTA/view?usp=sharing

I hope somebody can help.

Comment: Can you remember what is the last program you installed before this(crashs while installing)?

Comment: if i remember right it should be discord

Comment: Did you change the windows registry when you installed it, or did it ask you to accept the change in registry? Also try to scan you computer for virus/malware if you have a anti-virus software.

Comment: no, it didnt ask for any changes.

Comment: [I would run a SFC on the system](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929833)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to uninstall the software(discord) with a 3rd party uninstaller(eg Revo uninstaller). This will make sure everthing that is related to this software is deleted. Hope this help.

ps. Reinstall it if it doesn't help :D

Comment: thanks, but i seems to have fixed it. Seemingly the WOW64 entry in the MSI Service regedit key was missing.